# get and set in my class make my program break?

Tags: c#

this is in a class
why does the get and set on MySales, and theUnits make my program not work correctly?
ive tried to comment it out, delete it and nothing will work. I cant figure out why it is not working

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace project_5
{
    public class salesinvoice
    {
        private double Netmoney;
        private double Newmoney;
        private double StateValue;
        private double LocalValue;
        private double stateTax = 0.0745;
        private double localTax = 0.025;

        public double theUnits
        {
            get
            {
                return theUnits;
            }
            set
            {
                theUnits = value;
            }
        }          
        public double MySales
        {
            get
            {
                return MySales;
            }
            set
            {
                MySales = value;
            }
        }        
        public salesinvoice()
        {
            Netmoney = 0;
            Newmoney = 0;
        }
        public double Getmoney()
        {
            return Netmoney;
        }
        public double GetNewmoney()
        {
            return Newmoney;
        }
        public double GetStateValue()
        {
            return StateValue;
        }
        public double GetLocalValue()
        {
            return LocalValue;
        }
        public void NetSales()
        {
            Netmoney = theUnits * MySales;
        }

        public void StateTax()
        {
            StateValue = Netmoney * stateTax;
        }

        public void LocalTax()
        {
            LocalValue = Netmoney * localTax;
        }

        public void GrossSales()
        {
            Newmoney = Netmoney + StateValue + LocalValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have made recursive properties. So `MySales` returns `MySales` which returns `MySales` which returns `MySales` which returns `MySales` which returns `MySales` which returns `MySales` which returns `MySales` which returns `MySales` which returns `MySales` which returns `MySales` which returns `MySales` which returns `MySales` etc...

Comment: I agree with @DavidG

Answer (score 0):

If you want C# to generate the accessors for you, just use

```
public double theUnits { get; set;}
```

If you want to handle them yourself, you need a private copy like so:

```
private double _theUnits;
public double theUnits { 
    get { return this._theUnits; } 
    set { this._theUnits = value; }
}
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Format specifier was invalid.

Comment: never mind. I got it fixed. all I had to do was comment out the first string and delete s1 and it worked.